# Java Convert one Class to another class

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

Suppose I have 2 classes one is CustomerForm with following attribute name, password. Another class CustomerDomain with following same attribute name, password. I want to convert CustomerForm object to CustomerDomain. What is the most popular and convenient way?

Actually I am using Spring Boot, FormValidation and save to DB.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **com.google.gson.Gson** for converting one class object to another.

First convert class A's object to json String and then convert Json string to class B's object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(customerFormObject);

CustomerDomain customerDomainObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, CustomerDomain.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destination)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) for more info [BeanUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html)

Copy the property values of the given **source bean** into the **target bean.

**Note:** The source and target classes do not have to match or even be derived from each other, as long as the properties match. Any bean properties that the source bean exposes but the target bean does not will silently be ignored.

This is just a convenience method. For more complex transfer needs, consider using a full BeanWrapper.

Answer (score 0):

BeanUtils.copyProperties, as suggested by @pragnani-kinnera, would work just fine.  I prefer to avoid using it, though. Under the covers, BeanUtils uses reflection, which is best avoided unless necessary. It is slow and prone to breakage during refactoring.

For such a simple conversion, the easiest approach is the most straightforward:

```
   CustomerDomain customerDomain = new CustomerDomain();
   customerDomain.setName(customerForm.getName());
   customerDomain.setPassword(customerForm.getPassword());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the parameterized constructor of `CustomerDomain` class we can do this:

Here,
`formToDomain()` returns the resulting object by passing the object we need to convert.

```java
public CustomerDomain formToDomain(CustomerForm cutomerForm)
{
    CustomerDomain cDomain = new CustomerDomain(
        cutomerForm.getUname(), cutomerForm.getPassword()
    );
    return cDomain;     
}
```